# Valid, but worthless syntax in switch-case?

Tags: c, switch-statement, language-lawyer

Through a little typo, I accidentally found this construct:

```
int main(void) {
    char foo = 'c';

    switch(foo)
    {
        printf("Cant Touch This\n");   // This line is Unreachable

        case 'a': printf("A\n"); break;
        case 'b': printf("B\n"); break;
        case 'c': printf("C\n"); break;
        case 'd': printf("D\n"); break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the `printf` at the top of the `switch` statement is valid, but also completely unreachable.

I got a clean compile, without even a warning about unreachable code, but this seems pointless.

Should a compiler flag this as unreachable code?
Does this serve any purpose at all?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler already warn you about dead code in general?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question:  **YES** the compiler should warn against unreachable code. **NO** this bit was *NOT* flagged as unreachable.

Comment: @KerrekSB tried to reproduce: My GCC 5.3.1 doesn't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: My [GCC 7 does](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fokam99wkp5KgwEH) :-)

Comment: GCC has a special flag for this. It's `-Wswitch-unreachable`

Comment: @EliSadoff well, GCC 7 does seem to have that, but 5.3.1 doesn't know that flag :)

Comment: *"Does this serve any purpose at all?"* Well, you can `goto` in and out of the otherwise unreachable part, which may be useful for various hacks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wouldn't that be such for all unreachable code?

Comment: @EliSadoff Indeed. I guess it doesn't serve any *special* purpose. I bet it is allowed just because there is no reason to forbid it. After all, `switch` is just a conditional `goto` with multiple labels. There are more or less same restrictions on it's body as you would have on a regular block of code filled with goto labels.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The body doesn't even have to be a block. Any statement will do.

Comment: @PSkocik Huh, who would have thought.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: http://ideone.com/8XKE7 look where the `do {` is.

Comment: Worth pointing out that @MooingDuck s example is a variant on Duff's device (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device)

Comment: what I don't get is what's the difference in behavior when we look at duff's device vs. the `printf` in OP. why is one reached, and the other never? is it just because of the fall-through in the last case? could a for loop be used instead of the while? i.e., are "both ends of the loop a goto target"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Re "you can goto in and out of the otherwise unreachable part": If you can do that, the code is obviously not unreachable. Duh. The `printf` in the OP cannot be reached, period.

Comment: @dlatikayYes, one can think of both ends of a loop as labels (just imagine how a loop would be coded without loop constructs). While a `for` and a `while` loop technically only need a label at the beginning, a `do..while` loop has a virtual label at the end as well which is jumped to with a `continue`, in order to check the end condition.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Please read my comment closely. I know that, and that why I said "*otherwise* unreachable".

Comment: Another reason I don't touch C with a ten-foot stick; the compiler is just fine with stuff like this :)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Perhaps not the most useful, but not *completely* worthless. You may use it to declare a local variable available within `switch` scope.

```
switch (foo)
{
    int i;
case 0:
    i = 0;
    //....
case 1:
    i = 1;
    //....
}
```

The standard (`N1579 6.8.4.2/7`) has the following sample:

> EXAMPLE    In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>     int i = 4;
>     f(i);
> case 0:
>     i = 17;
>     /* falls through into default code */
> default:
>     printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never
>   initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the `printf` function will
>   access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to the function `f` cannot be reached.

**P.S.** BTW, the sample is not valid C++ code. In that case (`N4140 6.7/3`, emphasis mine):

> A program that jumps<sup>90</sup> from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a
>   point where it is in scope is ill-formed ***unless the variable has scalar type***, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the
>   preceding types ***and is declared without an initializer*** (8.5).
>
> ---
>
> <sup>90) The transfer from the condition of a `switch` statement to a case label is considered a jump in this respect.</sup>

So replacing `int i = 4;` with `int i;` makes it a valid C++.

Comment: "... but is never initialized ..." Looks like `i` is initialized to 4, what am I missing?

Comment: Note that if the variable is `static`, it will be initialized to zero, so there's a safe usage for this as well.

Comment: @yano We always jump over the `i = 4;`initialization, so it never takes place.

Comment: Hah of course! ... whole point of the question ... geez. The desire is strong to delete this stupidity

Comment: Nice! Sometimes I needed a temp variable inside a `case`, and always had to use different names in each `case` or define it outside the switch.

Answer (score 99):

> Does this serve any purpose at all?

Yes. If instead of a statement, you put a declaration before the first label, this can make perfect sense:

```
switch (a) {
  int i;
case 0:
  i = f(); g(); h(i);
  break;
case 1:
  i = g(); f(); h(i);
  break;
}
```

The rules for declarations and statements are shared for blocks in general, so it's the same rule that allows that that also allows statements there.

---

Worth mentioning as well is also that if the first statement is a loop construct, case labels may appear in the loop body:

```
switch (i) {
  for (;;) {
    f();
  case 1:
    g();
  case 2:
    if (h()) break;
  }
}
```

Please don't write code like this if there is a more readable way of writing it, but it's perfectly valid, and the `f()` call is reachable.

Comment: @MatthieuM Duff's Device does have case labels inside a loop, but starts with a case label before the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should upvote for the interesting example or downvote for the utter madness of writing this in a real program :). Congrats for diving into the abyss and returning back in one piece.

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer: If the code is part of a loop, as it is in Duff's Device, `{ /*code*/ switch(x) { } }` may look cleaner but it is also *wrong*.

Answer (score 40):

There is a famous use of this called [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device).

```
int n = (count+3)/4;
switch (count % 4) {
  do {
    case 0: *to = *from++;
    case 3: *to = *from++;
    case 2: *to = *from++;
    case 1: *to = *from++;
  } while (--n > 0);
}
```

Here we copy a buffer pointed to by `from` to a buffer pointed to by `to`.  We copy `count` instances of data.

The `do{}while()` statement starts before the first `case` label, and the `case` labels are embedded within the `do{}while()`.

This reduces the number of conditional branches at the end of the `do{}while()` loop encountered by roughly a factor of 4 (in this example; the constant can be tweaked to whatever value you want).

Now, optimizers can sometimes do this for you (especially if they are optimizing streaming/vectorized instructions), but without profile guided optimization they cannot know if you expect the loop to be large or not.

In general, variable declarations can occur there and be used in every case, but be out of scope after the switch ends.  (note any initialization will be skipped)

In addition, control flow that isn't switch-specific can get you into that section of the switch block, as illustrated above, or with a `goto`.

Comment: Of course, this would still be possible without allowing statements above the first case, as the order of `do {` and `case 0:` don't matter, both serve to place a jump target on the first `*to = *from++;`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd argue that putting the `do {` is more readable. Yes, arguing about readability for Duff's Device is stupid and pointless and likely a simple way to go mad.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You should check out Simon Tatham’s [Coroutines in C](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html). Or maybe not.

Comment: @JonasSchäfer Amusingly, that is basically what C++20 coroutines are going to do for you.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you are using gcc on Linux, it would have given you a warning if you're using 4.4 or earlier version.

The -Wunreachable-code option [was removed in gcc 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html) onward.

Comment: Having experienced the issue first hand always helps!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The general issue of gcc warnings being susceptible to the particular set of optimization passes selected is still true, unfortunately, and makes for a poor user experience. It's really annoying to have a clean Debug build followed by a failing Release build :/

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It would seem that such a warning would be extremely easy to detect in cases involving grammatical rather than semantic analysis [e.g. code follows an "if" which has returns in both branches], and make it easier to stifle "annoyance" warnings.  On the other hand, there are some cases where it's useful to have errors or warning in release builds that aren't in debug builds (if nothing else, in places where a hack which is put in for debugging is supposed to be cleaned up for release).

Comment: @supercat: Well, `#ifndef NDEBUG` allows debug only code sections and `#pragma warning` (I think) lets you write your own warning. However, my problem is more than having `-Wuninitialized` only work for maybe 30% of its potential reach in Debug and 100% in Release mean that you have to compile in both modes when developing, which slows down the edit-compile-test cycle (or you put it off 'till the end, and then discover that your approach has a flaw)... Clang manages to have such warnings have 100% coverage in Debug, I don't see why gcc couldn't.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: If significant semantic analysis would be required to discover that a certain variable will always be false at some spot in the code, code which is conditional upon that variable being true would be found to be unreachable only if such analysis were performed.  On the other hand, I would consider a notice that such code was unreachable rather differently from a warning about syntactically-unreachable code, since it should be entirely *normal* to have various conditions be possible with some project configurations but not others.  It may at times be helpful for programmers...

Comment: ...to know why some configurations generate larger code than others [e.g. because a compiler could regard some condition as impossible in one configuration but not another] but that doesn't mean that there's anything "wrong" with code which could be optimized in that fashion with some configurations.

Answer (score 11):

Not only for variable declaration but advanced jumping as well. You can utilize it well if and only if you're not prone to spaghetti code.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    switch(i)
    {
        nocase:
        printf("no case\n");

        case 0: printf("0\n"); break;
        case 1: printf("1\n"); goto nocase;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
1
no case
0 /* Notice how "0" prints even though i = 1 */
```

It should be noted that switch-case is one of the fastest control flow clauses. So it must be very flexible to the programmer, which sometimes involves cases like this.

Comment: And what is difference between `nocase:` and `default:`?

Comment: @i486 When`i=4` it does not trigger `nocase`.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar that's what I mean.

Comment: Why the heck would one do that instead of simply putting case 1 before case 0 and using fallthrough?

Comment: @JonasWielicki In this objective, you could do that. But this code is just a display case of what can be done.

Answer (score 11):

It should be noted, that there are virtually no structural restrictions on the code within the `switch` statement, or on where the `case *:` labels are placed within this code*. This makes programming tricks like [duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) possible, one possible implementation of which looks like this:

```
int n = ...;
int iterations = n/8;
switch(n%8) {
    while(iterations--) {
        sum += *ptr++;
        case 7: sum += *ptr++;
        case 6: sum += *ptr++;
        case 5: sum += *ptr++;
        case 4: sum += *ptr++;
        case 3: sum += *ptr++;
        case 2: sum += *ptr++;
        case 1: sum += *ptr++;
        case 0: ;
    }
}
```

You see, the code between the `switch(n%8) {` and the `case 7:` label is definitely reachable...

---

* <sub>As [supercat thankfully pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727415/valid-but-worthless-syntax-in-switch-case#comment70700365_41738481): Since C99, neither a `goto` nor a label (be it a `case *:` label or not) may appear within the scope of a declaration that contains a VLA declaration. So it's not correct to say that there are *no* structural restrictions on the placement of the `case *:` labels. However, duff's device predates the C99 standard, and it does not depend on VLA's anyway. Nevertheless, I felt compelled to insert a "virtually" into my first sentence due to this.</sub>

Comment: The addition of variable-length arrays led to the imposition of structural restrictions related to them.

Comment: @supercat What kind of restrictions?

Comment: Neither a `goto` nor `switch/case/default` label may appear within the scope of any variably-declared object or type.  This effectively means that if a block contains any declarations of variable-length-array objects or types, any labels must precede those declarations.  There's a confusing bit of verbiage in the Standard which would suggest that in some cases the scope of a VLA declaration extends to the entirety of a switch statement; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752072/meaning-of-this-rule-about-variable-length-arrays-and-switch-statements for my question on that.

Comment: @supercat: You just misunderstood that verbiage (which I presume is why you deleted your question). It imposes a requirement on the scope in which a VLA may be defined. It doesn't extend that scope, it just makes certain VLA definitions invalid.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah, I had misunderstood it.  The weird use of the present tense in the footnote made things confusing, and I think the concept could have been better expressed as a prohibition: "A switch statement whose body contains a VLA declaration within it shall not include any switch or case labels within the scope of that VLA declaration".

Answer (score 10):

You got your answer related to the [required `gcc` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) `-Wswitch-unreachable` to generate the warning, this answer is to elaborate on the *usability* / *worthyness* part.

Quoting straight out of `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
> int i = 4;
> f(i);
> case 0:
> i = 17;
> /* falls through into default code */
> default:
> printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> **the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage
>   duration (within the block) but is never initialized**, and thus if the
>   controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the `printf`
>   function will access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to
>   the function `f` cannot be reached.

Which is very self-explanatory. You can use this to define a locally scoped variable which is available only within the `switch` statement scope.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to implement a "loop and a half" with it, although it might not be the best way to do it:

```
char password[100];
switch(0) do
{
  printf("Invalid password, try again.\n");
default:
  read_password(password, sizeof(password));
} while (!is_valid_password(password));
```

Comment: @RichardII Is it a pun or what? Please explain.

Comment: @Dancia He's saying that this is pretty clearly _not_ the best way to do something like this, and "might not" is something of an understatement.