# Print statement in if, switch and while condition of c

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement, printf

Can someone explain why the code prints "HelloWorld" and not "HelloWorldThere" ? Also why does it print anything at all as there are no conditions in if or switch statements ? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    if(printf("Hello"))
        switch(printf("World"))
            while(printf("There"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about what `printf` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value).

Comment: And about `switch` statement too ... Your code is totally a non-sense.

Comment: About [`switch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/switch): "If expression evaluates to a value that doesn't match any of the case: labels, and the default: label is not present, none of the switch body is executed." -- no `case` labels, so nothing to match the expression, and no `default` label, so nothing happens.

Comment: I've been writing C professionally for nearly 20 years and never knew this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023601/can-i-put-code-outside-of-cases-in-a-switch.  (Edited to provide a better link)

Comment: Does this compile? Also use braces

Comment: @EdHeal: [Yes, it compiles and runs](https://ideone.com/iB5NUz), and produces the output described by the OP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid, but worthless syntax in switch-case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727415/valid-but-worthless-syntax-in-switch-case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty straightforward: `printf("Hello")` returns 5 (the number of characters written). 5 is not 0, so it's considered "true" for the purposes of the if, so then `printf("World")` also returns 5, the switch looks for a `case 5:`, doesn't find one, and stops there.

Answer (score 5):

For starters, let's consider what the function `printf` returns. From the C Standard

> 3 The `printf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or
>   a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

So the condition of this `if` statement

```
if(printf("Hello"))
```

evaluates to true because `printf()` returns a non-zero value.

Then this `switch` statement

```
switch(printf("World"))
```

is evaluated.

Now let's consider how the `switch` statement works. From the C Standard

> 4 A `switch` statement causes control to jump to, into, or past the
>   statement that is the switch body, depending on the value of a
>   controlling expression, and on the presence of a default label and the
>   values of any case labels on or in the switch body. A case or default
>   label is accessible only within the closest enclosing switch
>   statement.

As the body statement of the `switch` statement does not have a label (including the default label) then the control is passed past the body statement. That is, the `while` statement (that is a body statement of the `switch` statement) is not executed.

If you want to get the expected by you result then for example insert the label `default`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(printf("Hello"))
        switch(printf("World"))
            default: while(printf("There"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
}
```

In this case the program output is

```
HelloWorldThere
```

Or use a null-statement as the body statement of the switch statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(printf("Hello"))
        switch(printf("World")); // <==
            while(printf("There"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
}
```

Comment: Why does the program print "HelloWorldThere" when we add semi-colon?

Comment: @ChinmayVemuri Now the body statement of the switch statement is a nul statement. So the while statement is a separate statement that is executed after the switch statement.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. Thanks for the reply !